# JSON nested array deserializer

Tags: asp.net, json

I have a nested JSON , and all thing are okay with me but there is one part of it I am not able to get the data from it ,please tack a look at my JSON string :

[Nested JSOn](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb260275)

I was able to extrac the order and customer details but when it comes to the order items I was not able to get it from that JSON string since it is object and the object contains a list of arrays, so any suggestions for me to extract those arrays items

[image: yellow one is the issue :'(]

Comment: What do you use for deserialization? Any deserialization libraries like Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: It is not an array but JSON contained in JSON.  You have to run multiple deserializations, one for the outer data then put the value of ItemDetails and CustomerDetails through.

Comment: @raderick
yes I am using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm but the inner one I tried to validate it and it is not JSON valid format

Comment: @HAJJAJ if you replace `\"` with `"` and remove quote signs before braces, it's parsed fine: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbea8855

Comment: If you use software to pull the data it should parse fine. The data is encoded by the website you are using to test.

Answer (score 0):

Use the base object to read the main JSON then the `CustmerDetails` class and the `ItemDetails` class for the internal JSON items.

Here are the classes used to read the data:

```
public class BaseObject
{
    public string mobileapp_request_id { get; set; }
    public string CustmerDetails { get; set; }
    public string PaymentMethodID { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string brand_id { get; set; }
    public string specialrequest { get; set; }
    public string ItemDetails { get; set; }
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class CustmerDetails
{
    public string country_id { get; set; }
    public string block { get; set; }
    public string apartment { get; set; }
    public string avenue { get; set; }
    public string floor { get; set; }
    public string landmark { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string location_id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string city_id { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string building { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string address_id { get; set; }
    public string save_address { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string phone_number { get; set; }
}

public class Toppingsarray
{
    public string product { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string topping_id { get; set; }
    public string selection_id { get; set; }
    public string option_id { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetails
{
    public string main_option_id { get; set; }
    public string main_selection_id { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public List<Toppingsarray> toppingsarray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but how I will loop thru it ?

Comment: @HAJJAJ One could use a ForEach loop to iterate the items.